# SNS subscription filter policy - An error occurred while setting attribute subscription filter policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I am working with a S3 bucket which triggers a message to SNS topic when there is an object created. The event notification is created on S3 bucket level so whenever there is any object created on the bucket the message gets published to SNS which eventually triggers my lambda function.

However this S3 bucket has a lot of folders and subfolders, and I am only trying to setup the notification events on two path out of these. Lets say theses path are 'test/test1' and 'test2/test3'. Now when I attach this SNS topic to my lambda, my lambda is getting triggered on every events happening on the bucket.

I am trying to use Subscription filter policy in SNS to accomplish this but nothing seems to work. Here is my filter policy

```
    {
  "s3.object.key": {
     "FilterPolicy": "starts-with",
     "FilterValue": "test/test1"
  },
  "s3.object.key": {
     "FilterPolicy": "starts-with", 
     "FilterValue": "test2/test3"
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting attribute subscription filter policy. Invalid parameter: FilterPolicy: "FilterPolicy" must be an object or an array at [Source: (String)"{"s3/object/key":{"FilterPolicy":"starts-with","FilterValue":"test2/test3"}}"; line: 1, column: 35]
```

Also, I do not have access to modify the existing S3 bucket notification configuration directly. Since the event notification is already set at the bucket level, adding another event notification rule to that bucket is not possible either. Configuring the filtering through SNS would be the ideal approach in my situation if that can work.

Comment: Examples are also in: [Introducing payload-based message filtering for Amazon SNS | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/)